# Map Reduce algorithm design (mongodb prefered)

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm quite new to map reduce design. I use mongodb as backend and map reduce engine.

On a simple dataset like :

```
day, value
```

where value is -1, 0 or 1, I want to add duration to each row where duration is the number of **consecutive** days a value is equal to 1 or -1.

Exemple input data set :

```
       day| value
2012-01-01|  1
2012-01-02|  1
2012-01-03|  1
2012-01-04| -1
2012-01-05| -1
2012-01-06|  0
2012-01-07|  1
2012-01-08|  1
```

Output should be :

```
       day| value | Duration
2012-01-01|  1    | 0
2012-01-02|  1    | 1
2012-01-03|  1    | 2
2012-01-04| -1    | 0
2012-01-05| -1    |-1
2012-01-06|  0    | 0
2012-01-07|  1    | 0
2012-01-08|  1    | 1
```

Is this feasible in a map reduce job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't look feasible for MapReduce. I'm not sure how MongoDB handles the partitioning of its input to its mappers, but if I remember correctly, tasks that rely on having previous knowledge of data outside of one mapper's chunk is not possible for MapReduce.

It's possible for MR to do this job within a certain chunk. Say that days 01/01 to 01/02 are sent to one mapper (from your example). Certainly you can get it to realize that the two days have the same value in a row.

However, what if another mapper gets days 01/03 to 01/04? This mapper won't know that days 1 and 2 before it have the same value as day 3 does, so it'll just output that its duration is 0. There's no way to get the data from a different mapper, as far I as can see.

It may just be better to do this just with straight-up java coding.

Comment: Thanks, it seems possible like you said if I restrict the duration with a max value (e.g. 3 days), I emit 3 values per day (inefficient but at least distributed). For now I'll go, as you suggested, for a good old iteration.